# Lambda + RDS Postgres not working

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I'm trying to make rds with postgres work with lambda, but no luck so far. I've read all other threads about it here, double-checked my Lambda VPC + Subnet config, it's the same as the RDS one, but still no luck connecting, what am I missing here?

Some screenshots to clarify:
[image]
[image][image]

Before, I enabled the Public access and I could connect through serverless offline.

Thanks!

EDIT ----
[image]

Comment: Hello @Leonardo. Do you have any logs from CloudWatch about execution of Lambda? Does your role used by Lambda has `AssumeRole` policy attached?

Comment: Can you post your security group details? have you opened the port to lambda?

Comment: Can you post the IAM policy attached to your Lambda, the execution role?

Comment: @strongjz the print provided has all the policies.

Comment: @jpact I couldn't find this role... All the policies that I have for this lambda is in the print, in the question :D

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran what you mean by opening port to lambda?

Comment: what are the rules in your security group? is it restricted to a paticular ip? or 0.0.0.0/0?

Comment: It is restricted to 0.0.0.0/0 only. Thanks!

Comment: @Leonardo you have listed only access policies. Trust policies are  within `Trust relationships` tab

Comment: @jpact just edited with the Trust Relationships image! Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the error message when you try to connect? The logs from the lamdba function.

Comment: It just does not connect and I get a timeout from the lambda, I don't have any specific error from the lambda.

Comment: Couple of questions: what is the Lambda timeout and can you share the inbound and outbound rules of the security groups that you have attached to the Lambda function and RDS?

Comment: Timeout is 10s, Inbound: PostgreSQL (5432)
TCP (6)
5432
0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Outbound: ALL Traffic
ALL
ALL
0.0.0.0/0

Comment: I am not proficient in Postgres. Is there grant access to everyone query in Postgres? If so, have you / can you run it and then try to connect it from Lambda again?

Comment: Actually it is, I was able to test my lambda offline (using serverless offline) and it actually worked ok, so I'm suspecting it may be related to ip addresses or vpc configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you verified your security group for your RDS service? It needs to allow access from the security groups given to your Lambda function. It is not enough that they are in the same VPC/subnets. The security group still needs to allow traffic on the ports for postgres (5432).

Note that for security groups you don't have to select an origin IP (which can be tricky for Lambda). But i notice you are giving your Lambda function the group sg-29aac25d. You can use that ID to give access to the RDS.

IAM policies should be irrelevant as you are authenticating against postgres. Unless your IAM doesn't allow your Lambda to execute, the problem is not IAM.

Comment: Thank you, after adding my default vpc to my rds security group it worked!